# Ошибка при клонировании репозитория на сервер

Tags: git, centos, bitbucket

Есть сервер на CentOS 6.
При попытке клонирования репозитория вылетает ошибка:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: Temporary failure in name resolution
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Что вы уже предприняли? Например, ping, nslookup.

Comment: а также и `cat /etc/resolv.conf` что говорит?

Comment: ну так настройте доступ в интернет на вашем сервере, и будет вам клонирование.

Comment: Не судите строго, в организации исчез админ, а навыков работы с CentOS ни у кого нет. Куда смотреть? и где настроить доступ в интернет?

Comment: Очевидно в гугл.

Comment: @0xdb: В первую очередь нужно проверить работу интернета. Пингуется ли bitbucket.org, другие сайты? В зависимости от этого уже дальше плясать. Возможно дело в блокировках роскомнадзора, например. Если вам еще нужна помощь - пишите (см. профиль), может быть вместе разберемся.

Comment: @Ovsyanka  Вы наверное ошиблись именем. Посмотрите, кто вопрос задал.  Спасибо за  предложение.

Comment: Да, действительно ошибся. @Антон Голубков, сообщение было адресовано вам.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрались. Действительно была проблема с интернетом